# Should APK Signature Scheme v3 be avoided in favor of v3.1?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-signing

Android 9/Pie/API 28 introduced [APK Signature Scheme v3](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v3). From [Android 9 release notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0#apk-key-rotation):

> This scheme has the option to include a proof-of-rotation record in its signing block for each signing certificate. This capability enables your app to be signed with a new signing certificate by linking the APK file's past signing certificates to the one with which it is now signed.

Key rotation can be helpful for old apps originally created with insecure keys. My understanding is that key rotation with APK Signature Scheme v3 requires manually managing the old and new keys and using [`apksigner`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner#usage-rotate). From [a May 2020 dev rel article on App Signing](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/answers-to-common-questions-about-app-signing-by-google-play-b28fef836af0):

> the current key upgrade process does not take advantage of the key rotation feature introduced in Android 9 (Pie) and above. We are currently investigating support for key rotation using app signing v3 for devices on these OS versions and will let the developer community know once it’s ready in a separate announcement.

The [APK Signature Scheme v3 docs](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v3) also have this warning that I don't understand:

> APK key rotation is not recommended before the release of Android 11.

When I look at [Android 11 release notes](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/about/android-11-release), I see:

> Several CLI commands for signing builds for release are changed in Android 11.

I can't find additional details. This seems to be just about tooling so I don't think it's relevant anymore.

Now I've found a [section on APK Signature Scheme v3.1](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/about/android-13-release) in the Android 13 release notes:

> This scheme is used by default when signing an APK with a rotated signing key and signing lineage, and allows a single APK to target rotation on Android 13 and later while avoiding the known issues with rotation on previous platform versions by using the original signing key in the v3.0 signature block.

What are the tradeoffs between:

- using key rotation with v3 and being able to have more devices using app updates signed with a stronger key
- using the v3.1 scheme and getting the stronger key out only to Android 13+ users

In particular, what are the "known issues" with v3 and how might those affect an app that uses it?